# AJAX Form always recall old php file

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form and submit data to php file named "process.php" via AJAX. It works if I directly run the form.html, but when I call the form.html from jQuery panel, sometimes it call another php file to do the process and sometimes the page jump into a blank page after submit. From the Chrome Developer Tools, the network tab, I found another php file (go.php) was called which was the file I previously called. I changed the form action from "go.php" to "process.php" but the "go.php" was still called. I tried to clear the browser cache but could not find the reason why the previous action php file was still called.

Do anyone have similar experience? I have no idea where the cache keep.

Code as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            cache: false, 
            type: 'POST', 
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            url: $('#myform').attr('action'), 
            complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
              $('#output').val(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }});
          return false;
        });
});
```

Content in form.html

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="campBlock">
        <fieldset>
            <form action="process.php" id="myform" name="myform">
                <label for="campname">Campaign Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="campname" id="campname"><br/>
                <label for="longdesc">Description</label>
                <textarea id="longdesc" name="longdesc"></textarea><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Create">
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Content of jQuery Panel

```
<div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-display="overlay">
    <ul data-role="listview">
     <li data-role="list-divider" style="height: 2em;"><img class="header" src="msgol-sm100.png"/></li>
      <li><a href="form.html" data-prefetch="false">Create Campaign</a></li>
      <li><a href="changepass.html" data-prefetch="false">Change Password</a></li>
    </ul><br/>
    <p><a data-role="button" data-rel="close">Close</a></p>
....
```

Comment: Change the submit button, for an input type='button' ...and the .submit event by .click event ...saludos ;)

Comment: There is no response when I click the button.

$('#createBtn').click(function(e) {
...
}

and change the tag as below

<input type="button" id="createBtn" value="Create">

Comment: Weird....i make this fiddle and in the network tab, the ajax call it's working... see here http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/jb4UY/